# mongoose findOne with sorting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a problem with a mongo request:

```
models.user.findOne(
    {},
    {
        sort: {
            date_register: -1
        }
    },
    function(err, result) {
        console.log(err);
}
```

I have

```
{ [MongoError: Error: Unsupported projection option: date_register] name: 'MongoError' }
```

as error

I'd like to get my users by date_register DESC

Thanks

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This will vary slightly depending on your version of mongoose, but the method signature for `findOne` looks something like this:

```
function findOne (conditions, fields, options, callback)
```

What you intend as `options` (the sort), mongoose is handling as `fields` (which fields to load).

You might try explicitly passing `null` for fields:

```
models.user.findOne({}, null, { sort: { date_register: -1 } }, callback);
```

But if you can, you should probably use the query API, which is clearer, like:

```
models.user.findOne({}).sort({ date_register: -1 }).exec(callback);
```

Comment: That second example looks broken to me.. Won't `.findOne({}).sort(..)` return the a record from Mongoose *then* sort the result? Ie. the sort will only be applied to the single record returned which, assuming Mongoose uses the underlying `.findOne()` function in Mongo, `returns the first document according to the natural order which reflects the order of documents on the disk.` http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/

Comment: No, because of the way the way mongoose queries work.  Many mongoose methods, if not passed a callback, will return a [Query](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) object which allows the query sent to mongoose to be built up in parts.  In the example `findOne` and `sort` are chained and finally constructed into a query when `exec` is called.

Comment: @numbers1311407, do we have ```findOne().sort()``` in mongo shell?