# Node.js sorting array with findOne

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm attempting to sort the array from Mongodb, `Image` elements in time descending order. The date is located within the array.
This is the current output:

```
"address": "Product Address 1",
"town": "Brighton",
"Image": [
  {
    "price": 1021,
    "time": "2020-09-13T12:06:34.079Z"
  },
  {
    "price": 1022,
    "time": "2020-09-13T12:18:50.270Z"
  },
  {
    "price": 1023,
    "time": "2020-09-13T12:37:22.499Z"
  }
  ]
```

What I need is for the following element first, followed by the remaining two array elements:

```
{
    "price": 1023,
    "time": "2020-09-13T12:37:22.499Z"
}
```

The code I have is :

```
  dbProduct.findOne({
                productId: productId
          
        },{'image.token':0}).then(dbRes => {
    
                if (dbRes !== null) {
                    res.apiSuccess({
                    town: dbRes.town,
                

    county: dbRes.county,
                postCode: dbRes.postCode,
                image: dbRes.image
  });
        } else {
            res.apiError(messages.product.not_found);
        }
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What specifically are you asking? How to create a sortable time from the existing data? How to sort natively using whatever `findOne` is from?

Comment: can you post the exact expected result? I am a bit confused with the example you posted plus the "remaining two elements"

Comment: The 3 Image elements shown (price,time) I want reversing. So the first image element needs to be {"price": 1023, "time": "2020-09-13T12:37:22.499Z"}, the second {"price": 1022, "time": "2020-09-13T12:18:50.270Z"} ..

Comment: Try using the [`.sort()`](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_sort.asp) method. The [`.limit()`](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_limit.asp) method might come in handy too if you wish to only have one result.

Comment: Only one record is returned with findOne(), so not sure if sort() will work here. Its the data in the Array I need re-ordering

Comment: You can use the `Array.sort()` method from javascript, or use aggregation to sort on the server side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongoose findOne with sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443069/mongoose-findone-with-sorting)

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it helps

```
 dbProduct.findOne({
                productId: productId
          
        },{'image.token':0},{sort: {image.$.time: -1 }}).then(dbRes => {
    
                if (dbRes !== null) {
                    res.apiSuccess({
                    town: dbRes.town,
                

    county: dbRes.county,
                postCode: dbRes.postCode,
                image: dbRes.image
  });
        } else {
            res.apiError(messages.product.not_found);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but makes no difference. I also tried sort: {'Image.time': -1}

Comment: check this post there is way to do this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443069/mongoose-findone-with-sorting